# How do protect and array from being altered via encapsulation in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, encapsulation

Consider the following code:

```
class Customers {
  private _list: Array<Person>;

  constructor() {
    this._list = [];
  }

  public get customerList(): Array<Person> {
    return this._list;
  }
}
```

Given that code, there doesn't appear to be any way to prevent a consumer to alter the `customerList` array in ways that I might not like.  For instance, a consumer could call

```
myCustomer.customerList.slice(1, 2);
```

and remove customers without "permission".

In other languages I'd expose the list as an `IEnumerable<T>` and then provide specific removal methods if desired.

How do I properly encapsulate and protect the 'customerList()' property in TypeScript?

(Perfectly happy to admit I'm going about this the entirely wrong way.....)

Comment: First, `slice` doesn't alter the underlying array, it's `splice` that does it. Second, have you considered exposing the private list as just `ReadonlyArray<Person>`? The interface prevents the client code from altering the array.

Comment: @WiktorZychla -  ReadonlyArray<T> was exactly what I was looking for and what I didn't know existed.  Thanks.  Will give you credit if you write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TypeScript's `ReadonlyArray<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-properties) is exactly what you are looking for. The interface prevents the client code from altering the array.